# Losing detail of pdf images in latex

Tags: graphics, pdf, r

I have a plot in R and i saved as a pdf.
Now i want to include that in latex. That's the pdf file in R

[image: pdf in R]

and in LATEX[image]

i'm getting crazy on this, why the points on the plot simply disappear????

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried printing out the file from each application? Do the plot marks appear when you zoom in? If both fails, can you provide the file in question?

Comment: What version has the PDF you are trying to include in your LaTeX document, and which engine is used?  E.g., pdflatex outputs PDF 1.5 (afaik), so includes should have at most that version.

Comment: Are the points annotations?

Comment: Ok @Moss_the_TeXie i think that you have got the point. I m using pdfLatex and the version of the pdf is 1.4. So what i'm supposed to do right now? Thanks

Comment: If you can provide the PDF file, maybe some of the resident gurus can help you... :-)

Comment: One possibility is that the marks use some odd font. Xelatex or Lualatex might help there.

Comment: Hmm.  If the version of the R PDF to be included is <i>less</i> than the version of the PDF it is included in, then the result should be ok.  Maybe the R PDF does something funny in its code, relying on some code lib which gets mangled or omitted in the process of including?

Comment: Second thought:  If you’re targetting print (only) you could try to rasterize the R PDF (at the print resolution) so no funny things can happen anymore.  The down side is boosting the file size in a probably horrible way (which doesn’t really matter if it is print only).

Comment: Changing to Xelatex or Lualatex doesn't help

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Actually no. But  i found it's a problem I ecountered only with this particular plot. Never mind i'll save it as jpeg or png

Comment: Did you consider the answer I provided? If it's helpful then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is *not* a LaTeX question in my opinion. Maybe it's better to ask the question
>   in another community (see the links I provided).

As far as I know, **R** doesn't embed the fonts in pdf files.

- Have a look at this **R** *function*: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/embedFonts.html or http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/grDevices/html/embedFonts.html
- Related **R** *function*: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/extrafont.html
- The *package* **Cairo** seems to embedd fonts automatically: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html or https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/cairo.html (`cairo_pdf`).
- Related *question*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542302
- Related *question*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568847
- Related *blog article*: http://www.benjack.io/2016/06/11/embed-fonts.html
- Adobe specifies **14** so-called **base fonts** that do not need to be embedded in pdf files because Adobe Reader (kind of, see Wikipedia article) knows this fonts, see here: http://www.enfocus.com/manuals/ReferenceGuide/PP/10/enUS/en-us/concept/c_aa1140975.html. Maybe this is the reason why **R** doens't embed fonts. See [PDF Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) article (section `Standard Type 1 Fonts (Standard 14 Fonts)`).
- As a **last ressort**, export it as a **PNG** image :).

> Be aware that your screen shot **"in LaTeX"** only shows in **"Texmaker viewer"**. `LaTeX` is *not* the pdf viewer! It's likely that the Texmaker pdf viewer doens't have access to the not embedded font whereas **Foxit** (your upper screen shot) has.